# How to free my Swap memory on Centos 5.9

Tags: linux, unix

Hi guys I need help steps to free my swap memory on CENTOS 5.9 during production. Also let me know can i add more swap in my existing swap memory during production time.

please let me the commands step by step.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you ask? Why do you need to free the swap memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, query the currently used swap partitions or files with

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

(and query the current state of the memory with the `free` command)

to remove a swap area on partition `/dev/sdc1`, use

```
swapoff /dev/sdc1
```

to add a swap area on partition `/dev/sdc2` use

```
swapon /dev/sdc2
```

you need to be root to run these; be *very careful*.

You could, e.g. if you need more swap than usual, use (temporarily) a file for swap (but using partitions is faster). For that, create a big file `/var/tmp/bigswap`, e.g of 8192 Mbytes using

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/tmp/bigswap bs=1M count=8192
```

then, make it a swap area with

```
mkswap /var/tmp/bigswap
```

at last, add it as swap using

```
swapon /var/tmp/bigswap
```

when you've done, remove it as swap using

```
swapoff /var/tmp/bigswap
```

and remove the file with `rm`

In general, permanent swap areas are defined in `/etc/fstab` (and activated using `swapon -a`).

See [swapon(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/swapon.8.html), [mkswap(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mkswap.8.html), [fstab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html)

Don't forget to read http://linuxatemyram.com/

PS. It is rarely useful to explicitly free the swap memory, since the kernel is managing it quite well.

Answer (score 2):

you can use swapon and swaoff utility:

```
sudo swapoff -a              # here -a option will disable all swap partitions
sudo swapon -a               # here -a option will enable all swap partitions
```